# Linear System - Laplace - Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, systems-of-equations

Can somebody help me? I need to find the determinant of the related matrix with Laplace's method. What is the easiest way to find it?

$x+y-z+w=1\\
x+2y+z-w=-1\\
y+2z-2w=-2\\
kx+3z=0$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you describe what Laplace's method is?  If so, can you start applying it and then ask when you are stuck?

Comment: I know that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}det(A_{ij})$.

So, $det(a)=(-1)^5k\left |\begin{matrix}
 1&-1  &1 \\ 
 2&1&-1 \\ 
 1& 2 & -2
\end{matrix}\right | + (-1)(3)\left |\begin{matrix}
 1&-1  &1 \\ 
 1&1&-1 \\ 
 0& 2 & -2
\end{matrix}\right |$

Is it right? @TravisJ

Comment: @Romeo I will just mention that it would probably have been better if you included your work right away, and if you did it in the post rather than in a comment (where it is less visible). See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for more on adding context and asking good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are asking about the determinant of the linear system, which you wrote in your question, i.e.,
$$|A|=
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 1 &-1 & 1 \\
  1 & 2 & 1 &-1 \\
  0 & 1 & 2 &-2 \\
  k & 0 & 3 & 0 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

If you use [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) w.r.t. the fourth row you get:
$$|A|=
-k
\begin{vmatrix}
 1 &-1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 &-1 \\
 1 & 2 &-2 \\
\end{vmatrix}
-3
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 2 &-1 \\
  0 & 1 &-2 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
The you have to calculate these two $3\times3$ determinants. (I suppose this is what you were trying to do [in your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309534/linear-system-laplace-determinant/1318503#comment2659871_1309534). From what you wrote there is seems that you had the number $3$ in the second column of your matrix.)

You can then check the results online, for example, in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%5B%5B1%2C1%2C-1%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C2%2C1%2C-1%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C-2%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C3%2C0%5D%5D).

However, if you notice that the second row of the matrix $A$ is exactly the sum of the first row and the third row, then you know that the rows are linearly dependent and thus the determinant is zero. (But you should get the same result using your method.)